# IBM Cloud: How to change session expiration?

Tags: security, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-iam

I am using IBM Cloud and sometimes when coming back from a coffee break I have to enter my credentials again. Is there a way to change the session expiration time? Could it be done programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The settings can be changed either in the IBM Cloud console (UI) or via REST API. In the UI you have to access the [Identity and Access Management (IAM) settings](https://cloud.ibm.com/iam/settings).
[image: IBM Cloud IAM settings]

The IBM Cloud API docs have a section for the platform services. There, the IAM services can be found. They have an API to fetch the current account settings and [update the account settings](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/iam-identity-token-api#updateaccountsettings). It includes the configuration values for **session_expiration_in_seconds** and **session_invalidation_in_seconds** to control the session expiration. You could use **curl** to update the settings like this:

```
curl -X PUT 'https://iam.cloud.ibm.com/v1/accounts/ACCOUNT_ID/settings/identity' 
-H 'Authorization: Bearer TOKEN' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
-d '{
  "session_expiration_in_seconds": 3600,
  "session_invalidation_in_seconds": 1800
}'
```